# Using GroupLayout in a JPanel to align JTextFields and JLabels?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, grouplayout

So, this is my problem: I used the oracle documents as an example for my project, but when i run the program all it shows up as is a box with "weekly pay:" in the middle. What am I doing wrong?

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.setTitle("Weekly Pay");
window.setSize(300, 150);
window.setResizable(false);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Color lGray = new Color(209, 209, 209);
GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(window);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(lGray);
panel.setLayout(layout);
layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

JLabel id = new JLabel("ID Number");
JLabel hw = new JLabel("Hourly Wage");
JLabel rh = new JLabel("Regular Hours");
JLabel oh = new JLabel("Overtime Hours");
JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate");
JTextField idEntry = new JTextField(); //where the user imputs their ID
JTextField hwEntry = new JTextField(); //where the user imputs their hourly wage
JTextField rhEntry = new JTextField(); //where the user imputs their regular hours
JTextField ohEntry = new JTextField(); //where the user imputs their overtime hours
JLabel wp = new JLabel("Weekly Pay:");    

GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();    
hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
  addComponent(id).addComponent(hw).addComponent(rh).addComponent(oh).addComponent(calc));
hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
  addComponent(idEntry).addComponent(hwEntry).addComponent(rhEntry).addComponent(ohEntry).addComponent(wp));
layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);

GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();    
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
    addComponent(id).addComponent(idEntry));
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
    addComponent(hw).addComponent(hwEntry));
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
    addComponent(rh).addComponent(rhEntry));
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
    addComponent(oh).addComponent(ohEntry));
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).
    addComponent(calc).addComponent(wp));
layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);

window.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems:  you set the group layout manager on the frame, not the panel, and you don't actually put the panel onto the frame/window (since there is something in java UI programming called a window, I question the naming of the variable holding the frame to be 'window').

Instead of "GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(window);", use "GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel); // after panel is constructed, of course".

Then use "window.add(panel);" to put the panel in the frame/window; I would put this and "window.pack();" just before "window.setVisible(true);"

rc

Comment: If that answered your question, please mark it as "answered" (the check mark next to the answer).  As you use StackOverflow for other questions, they are more likely to be answered if you have marked answers this way on previous questions.

Comment: That side-note about frame/window is a bit unfair. Frame extends from Window, so it's a window too.

Comment: I think it best, and in fact necessary for making things acceptably good, to be careful not to confuse readers.  A JFrame is extended from Frame, Window, Container, and Component, specifically because it has characteristics these other things do not.  I know that the word window has yet other meanings, and would guess that the OP was thinking of those, but it is misleading to other programmers to confuse the two.  If you think it's all right that he call it "window" because Window is in the inheritance hierarchy, I guess you would also think it all right if he called this JFrame "component".